# FreeBSD: How to know real file size on zfs with compression on?

Tags: freebsd, zfs, find, ls, du

I'm using zfs on my **FreeBSD 9.0 x64** and pretty happy with it, but I find it hard to count directory real, not compressed, size.

Surely I can walk over the directory and count every file size with ls, but I'd expect some extra key for du for that purpose.

So, **how can I tell the directory size for dir placed on zfs with compression on**?

Thamk you in advance for the advice, I simple can't rememeber there is no such a 'simple' way, without 'find ./ -type d -exec ls -l '{}' \; | awk ...'!

Comment: See this answer for some solutions: http://serverfault.com/questions/254013/file-size-with-zfs-compression

Comment: If using deduplication, what would you consider the "real" size to be?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the `du` with its `-A` flag:

```
root@pg78:/usr/local/pgsql/data/base/218204 # du -A -h 221350.219
1.0G    221350.219
root@pg78:/usr/local/pgsql/data/base/218204 # du -h 221350.219
501M    221350.219
```

Very handy. It even works with `-d` for recursive goodness:

```
root@pg78:/usr/local/pgsql/data/base # du -h -c -d0 .
387G    .
387G    total
root@pg78:/usr/local/pgsql/data/base # du  -A -h -c -d0 .
518G    .
518G    total
```

Comment: Really good solution! And the best it is there "right from the box"!

Comment: Just a note, if your version of `du` doesn't have the -A option, -A is for "apparent size", which is available via `--apparent-size`. Ubuntu 16.04 / du 8.25 doesn't seem to have -A, so it seems like someone else might run into that issue.

Comment: Jim is right. It is -a or --apparent-size. At least on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Jim is wrong. It is not -a or --apparent-size for FreeBSD's du, which is what this question is about (very first word in the title, even). More troubling, using -A with FreeBSD's du gives results that are smaller than what zfs list reports, so clearly this is not correct. GNU's du *also* gives a smaller (although different) size to zfs list.

Answer (score 15):

You could install the GNU version of `du(1)`:

`cd /usr/ports/sysutils/coreutils && make install clean`

Then you can use the `--apparent-size` flag:

```
/space# zfs create space/comptest
/space# zfs set compression=on space/comptest
/space# dd if=/dev/zero of=/space/comptest/zerofile bs=1M count=40
/space/comptest# gdu
2K      .
/space/comptest# gdu --apparent-size
40961K  .
```

Comment: There is __NO__ reason to use a port for this. Use the base OS ``du`` with its ``-A`` flag.

Comment: This is useful for ZFS on Linux. GNU `du` doesn't have a `-A` option.

Comment: ZFS on Linux's `du` has `--apparent-size` from the comment on the accepted solution here: https://serverfault.com/a/434655/145009

Answer (score 2):

try to use zpool command :

```
zpool list
NAME      SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
storage  8.93T  6.59T  2.34T         -    60%    73%  2.13x  ONLINE  -
```

but df -sh shows resulting (not deduplicated size)

```
df -hT
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
storage        zfs        16T   14T  1.9T  89% /storage
```