# df reports zfs used space as 128K, not the actual used space

Tags: storage, zfs, disk-space-utilization, proxmox, lxc

I have a ZFS mirror pool in my Proxmox instance. I am trying to get it to mount to an LXC container read-only (preferably not giving full filesystem access) so I can have [Homepage](https://gethomepage.dev) detect the used and free space properly for monitoring purposes.

[Other serverfault questions and answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/362090/freebsd-how-to-know-real-file-size-on-zfs-with-compression-on) have reported that `df -hT` should be able to report used space of zfs filesystems properly (minus parity data, possibly compression or dedupe data, but I'm not looking for 100% accuracy here)

But for me, `df -hT` reports the total space as what's available, and the used space as 128K.

```
root@pve:~# df -hT /nvme
Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
nvme           zfs   590G  128K  590G   1% /nvme
```

/nvme is the toplevel zfs dataset is it not? Why does the space seem to be oddly calculated across these datasets?

```
root@pve:~# zfs list
NAME                     USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
nvme                     309G   590G   128K  /nvme
nvme/base-103-disk-0    43.4G   631G  2.19G  -
nvme/nvmecheck            96K   590G    96K  /mnt/nvmecheck
nvme/subvol-102-disk-0   554M  1.46G   554M  /nvme/subvol-102-disk-0
nvme/subvol-105-disk-0  1.71G  2.29G  1.71G  /nvme/subvol-105-disk-0
nvme/subvol-106-disk-0   625M  1.39G   625M  /nvme/subvol-106-disk-0
nvme/subvol-107-disk-0  3.37G  11.6G  3.37G  /nvme/subvol-107-disk-0
nvme/subvol-108-disk-0  1.18G  1.82G  1.18G  /nvme/subvol-108-disk-0
nvme/subvol-109-disk-0   533M  1.48G   533M  /nvme/subvol-109-disk-0
nvme/vm-100-disk-0      43.3G   624G  8.96G  -
nvme/vm-101-disk-0       132G   607G   115G  -
nvme/vm-104-disk-0      82.5G   661G  11.6G  -
```

FYI, `nvme/nvmecheck` is a dataset I made to see how child datasets would be calculated. It's even stranger with its reference.

Can anyone tell me what is going on? Maybe it's Debian's zfs implementation? Or something wrong with `df`?

zpool status is warning me that there are missing features with my zpool that I can run zpool upgrade, but I'm unsure if this is safe. My Proxmox is using the new boot tool, not legacy, so that should not be a concern.

zfs's `USEDDS` property may be related, but unsure:

```
root@pve:~# zfs list -o space nvme
NAME  AVAIL   USED  USEDSNAP  USEDDS  USEDREFRESERV  USEDCHILD
nvme   590G   309G        0B    128K             0B       309G
```

As you can see below, ZFS has a few properties where this `128K` may derive from also.

```
root@pve:~# zfs get all nvme
NAME  PROPERTY              VALUE                  SOURCE
nvme  type                  filesystem             -
nvme  creation              Sat Jul 22 20:53 2023  -
nvme  used                  309G                   -
nvme  available             590G                   -
nvme  referenced            128K                   -
nvme  compressratio         1.13x                  -
nvme  mounted               yes                    -
nvme  quota                 none                   default
nvme  reservation           none                   default
nvme  recordsize            128K                   default
nvme  mountpoint            /nvme                  default
nvme  sharenfs              off                    default
nvme  checksum              on                     default
nvme  compression           on                     local
nvme  atime                 off                    local
nvme  devices               on                     default
nvme  exec                  on                     default
nvme  setuid                on                     default
nvme  readonly              off                    default
nvme  zoned                 off                    default
nvme  snapdir               hidden                 default
nvme  aclmode               discard                default
nvme  aclinherit            restricted             default
nvme  createtxg             1                      -
nvme  canmount              on                     default
nvme  xattr                 on                     default
nvme  copies                1                      default
nvme  version               5                      -
nvme  utf8only              off                    -
nvme  normalization         none                   -
nvme  casesensitivity       sensitive              -
nvme  vscan                 off                    default
nvme  nbmand                off                    default
nvme  sharesmb              off                    default
nvme  refquota              none                   default
nvme  refreservation        none                   default
nvme  guid                  [redacted]             -
nvme  primarycache          all                    local
nvme  secondarycache        all                    default
nvme  usedbysnapshots       0B                     -
nvme  usedbydataset         128K                   -
nvme  usedbychildren        309G                   -
nvme  usedbyrefreservation  0B                     -
nvme  logbias               latency                default
nvme  objsetid              54                     -
nvme  dedup                 off                    default
nvme  mlslabel              none                   default
nvme  sync                  standard               default
nvme  dnodesize             legacy                 default
nvme  refcompressratio      1.00x                  -
nvme  written               128K                   -
nvme  logicalused           164G                   -
nvme  logicalreferenced     54.5K                  -
nvme  volmode               default                default
nvme  filesystem_limit      none                   default
nvme  snapshot_limit        none                   default
nvme  filesystem_count      none                   default
nvme  snapshot_count        none                   default
nvme  snapdev               hidden                 default
nvme  acltype               off                    default
nvme  context               none                   default
nvme  fscontext             none                   default
nvme  defcontext            none                   default
nvme  rootcontext           none                   default
nvme  relatime              on                     default
nvme  redundant_metadata    all                    default
nvme  overlay               on                     default
nvme  encryption            off                    default
nvme  keylocation           none                   default
nvme  keyformat             none                   default
nvme  pbkdf2iters           0                      default
nvme  special_small_blocks  0                      default
```

My zpool properties:

```
root@pve:~# zpool get all nvme
NAME  PROPERTY                       VALUE                          SOURCE
nvme  size                           928G                           -
nvme  capacity                       15%                            -
nvme  altroot                        -                              default
nvme  health                         ONLINE                         -
nvme  guid                           [redacted]                     -
nvme  version                        -                              default
nvme  bootfs                         -                              default
nvme  delegation                     on                             default
nvme  autoreplace                    off                            default
nvme  cachefile                      -                              default
nvme  failmode                       wait                           default
nvme  listsnapshots                  off                            default
nvme  autoexpand                     off                            default
nvme  dedupratio                     1.00x                          -
nvme  free                           782G                           -
nvme  allocated                      146G                           -
nvme  readonly                       off                            -
nvme  ashift                         12                             local
nvme  comment                        -                              default
nvme  expandsize                     -                              -
nvme  freeing                        0                              -
nvme  fragmentation                  12%                            -
nvme  leaked                         0                              -
nvme  multihost                      off                            default
nvme  checkpoint                     -                              -
nvme  load_guid                      [redacted]                     -
nvme  autotrim                       off                            default
nvme  compatibility                  off                            default
nvme  bcloneused                     0                              -
nvme  bclonesaved                    0                              -
nvme  bcloneratio                    1.00x                          -
nvme  feature@async_destroy          enabled                        local
nvme  feature@empty_bpobj            active                         local
nvme  feature@lz4_compress           active                         local
nvme  feature@multi_vdev_crash_dump  enabled                        local
nvme  feature@spacemap_histogram     active                         local
nvme  feature@enabled_txg            active                         local
nvme  feature@hole_birth             active                         local
nvme  feature@extensible_dataset     active                         local
nvme  feature@embedded_data          active                         local
nvme  feature@bookmarks              enabled                        local
nvme  feature@filesystem_limits      enabled                        local
nvme  feature@large_blocks           enabled                        local
nvme  feature@large_dnode            enabled                        local
nvme  feature@sha512                 enabled                        local
nvme  feature@skein                  enabled                        local
nvme  feature@edonr                  enabled                        local
nvme  feature@userobj_accounting     active                         local
nvme  feature@encryption             enabled                        local
nvme  feature@project_quota          active                         local
nvme  feature@device_removal         enabled                        local
nvme  feature@obsolete_counts        enabled                        local
nvme  feature@zpool_checkpoint       enabled                        local
nvme  feature@spacemap_v2            active                         local
nvme  feature@allocation_classes     enabled                        local
nvme  feature@resilver_defer         enabled                        local
nvme  feature@bookmark_v2            enabled                        local
nvme  feature@redaction_bookmarks    enabled                        local
nvme  feature@redacted_datasets      enabled                        local
nvme  feature@bookmark_written       enabled                        local
nvme  feature@log_spacemap           active                         local
nvme  feature@livelist               enabled                        local
nvme  feature@device_rebuild         enabled                        local
nvme  feature@zstd_compress          enabled                        local
nvme  feature@draid                  enabled                        local
nvme  feature@zilsaxattr             disabled                       local
nvme  feature@head_errlog            disabled                       local
nvme  feature@blake3                 disabled                       local
nvme  feature@block_cloning          disabled                       local
nvme  feature@vdev_zaps_v2           disabled                       local
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df` will report how much storage is used *by that mountpoint itself*, e.g. files that are currently stored directly in `/nvme` (not considering neither snapshots nor reservations). It seems there are just some subfolders for the other mountpoints in there, hence the little usage of `128K`.

The `USED` column of `zfs list` however shows the usage of the whole sub-tree, including children (and snapshots).

`zpool upgrade` is generally safe to run; the only drawback is that the pool then can only be used on systems that support *all* of the activated features, e.g. you might not be able to open it using a previous snapshot of the system or a rescue image.

Comment: Thank you. I found similar info. The frustration is Homepage does its space checks with df and my zfs pool is on the host, so the zfs command is inaccessible from the lxc container. I'll have to look into alternative methods, I guess.

Comment: Hmm... do you care about how much is currently used, or how much would be available for consumption?

Comment: Anyways, you can't get useful monitoring information about a whole ZFS pool just by looking at `du/df` output of a single zfs volume.